# SQL condition on firstname and lastname without append or concat

Tags: sql

You have 2 tables Customers and Blacklist, both with columns firstname and lastname.

How would you find good customers? Please note that I cannot append or concatenate lastname to firstname(or vice versa) because of character limit.

I think a left join would work. Please confirm.

```
select c.lastname,c.firstname
from Curtomers c
left join Blacklist b
ON (c.lastname = b.lastname
AND c.firstname = b.lastname)
where b.firstname is null
and b.lastname is null
```

Comment: but you have to look that `is null` ... or you will get bad customers :)

Comment: and no need to have `,b.firstname,b.lastname` in your select since they will be `NULL`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT    c.*
FROM      Customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT  *
  FROM    Blacklist b
  WHERE   c.firstname = b.firstname
    AND   c.lastname = b.lastname
)
```

I assume you're inferring a "good customer" to be one not in the `blacklist` table? Also, I have *no idea* what dbms you're using.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers C
LEFT OUTER JOIN Blacklist BL ON C.firstname = BL.firstname AND
                                C.lastname = BL.lastname   
WHERE BL.firstname IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
BlackList b ON c.FirstName = b.FirstName AND c.LastName = b.LastName
WHERE b.FirstName IS NULL
```

Have a look at this nice visual representation of JOINS

[Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from customers
minus
select *
from blacklist
```